# Web font not working on server when I move css file to its own folder

Tags: fonts

So I made the mistake of forgetting to put my external CSS file into it's own "css" folder in my root folder when I started this website.

Made a new folder in my root, pasted the CSS file into said folder, and made sure it linked properly to my HTML. All of the styling worked except for background images (there were 2).

Before I moved my CSS file, the code for the background images looked like this -

```
    background-image: url(images/main_bg.png);
```

I re-inputted it and then it looked like this, which worked. My background images were now showing up on my server and local host.

```
    background-image: url(../images/main_bg.png);
```

My font-kits, however, now do not show up. I tried adding the ".../" in front of each link, assuming it would work like the background images, but no luck. All the fonts are in their own folder on the server. This is what they look like in my style sheet -

```
    @font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansExtraboldItalic';
src: url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.svg#OpenSansExtraboldItalic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

How am I linking them wrong? It's probably a stupid answer right under my nose, but I'm getting annoyed lol.

Comment: Where is your `fonts` folder located?

Comment: ../ means one folder back, / means start at the root folder. Did you try /fonts/...? Also you have single quotes around your font urls and no single quotes around your image urls? URL('???') URL(???)

Comment: My root is called "kelseytest" then there is a folder called "fonts" where all the fonts are located. Before I moved the css to it's own folder, it worked fine with how I had it.

Comment: Ah-ha! Added "/../fonts" in front and it's working now. I'm ashamed of myself lol. Thank you guys C:

Answer (score 0):

Adding ../ to the url's should work, just like the images.
Everything in CSS is linked relative from the path of where the css-file is.
Have you moved the font-folder by accident?
Make sure in this setup that you have a font-folder in your root-folder.